# How Cancel button in JDialog reset the components values

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Consider I have 3 textfields and 3 checkboxes in a JDialog with OK and Cancel button. I updated the components (entered values in 2 textfield and 2 checkbox in selected state) and clicked the Cancel button. The components value needs to be get reset. Is the cancel operation performed using the below style of coding?

In JDialog opening event,

```
String str_txtf1 = txtfld1.getText();
String str_txtf2 = txtfld2.getText();
String str_txtf3 = txtfld3.getText();

boolean chbox1 = chkbox1.isSelected();
boolean chbox2 = chkbox2.isSelected();
boolean chbox3 = chkbox3.isSelected();
```

In cancel event,

```
txtfld1.setText(str_txtf1);
txtfld2.setText(str_txtf2);
txtfld3.setText(str_txtf3);

chkbox1.setSelected(chbox1);
chkbox2.setSelected(chbox2);
chkbox3.setSelected(chbox3);
```

Comment: Compile it, run it, see if it does what you want. If it does, then fine. If it doesn't, then fix it.

Comment: Why I asked this question is, if i have 100 components in my Jdialog. Am i suppose to create strings and boolean each time?. is there any optimized way to do it.

Comment: Why don't you recreate the dialog from scratch every time? That said, 100 components in a dialog? Ouch!

Comment: The Cancel button is supposed to cancel the JDialog.  You need a separate Reset or Clear button to clear all the dialog fields.  Users expect certain buttons to work in certain ways.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc : yes you are right, Canel button is expected to cancel the dialog. What if i modified the components and click the cancel button. My doubt is, above method is the only way to reset the components values on clicking the cancel button or any other optimized way is available?

Comment: "What if i modified the components and click the cancel button?"  You cancel the JDialog and ignore whatever is typed in the JDialog components.  That's what a Cancel button does.